# Cocos2d, can't import <cmath>?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This must be a big noob question, but... How come I can't import standard C libraries into my cocos2d project?

I typed `#import <cmath>` and it can't find the file... why?

And yet... The math functions seem to work already...?

Comment: would #import <math.h> work instead?

Comment: Yes. That one works.. So why not `<cmath>`?

Comment: cmath is c++. math.h is C. Objective C sits on top of C not C++, sort of speak.

Comment: I assume it will work if you change the file extension from .m to .mm to make the compiler treat the file as Objective-C++ rather than Objective-C code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll keep this in mind.